# What am I? (Identify the single word)

Tags: word

> You find me on a die, and
>   The flag of a peaceful island
>   I'm used on maps, but not many
>   I'm an old coin, but not a penny

**What am I?**

---

*I'm not a star, nor a letter/number.

If not solved, I'll provide a hint every 24 hours.*

Comment: My first puzzle. Having been part of PSE for a few months, I'm expecting either a) a correct answer in minutes b) answers that address the question but weren't something I thought of c) A slap on the wrist for a too-broad question!

Comment: Congrats on your first question!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are referring to

> a quincunx

It is a

> Roman coin, and also the arrangement of 5 dots on the "5" side of a die. It's an arrangement of stars on the Solomon Islands flag, and also refers to a specific map projection.

To elaborate a little more on one bit of trivia,

> the map projection is so-named because one pole is placed at the center of a square, and the other pole is mapped to all four corners of the square. The poles are therefore in the same relative positions as the five pips on a die.

Comment: Nicely done, that was quick!

Comment: Out of curiosity, which line was the key one for you? @eric-tressler

Comment: @phylyp probably the "old coin" because that one is hard to make a pun for

Comment: I was familiar with the name of the arrangement on a die; I suspected that it had other meanings, and a search confirmed my guess.

Comment: Ah, your involvement in the MathOverflow and Mathematics explains that!